# ¿Como traer images con nuxt 3 y el ssr activo?

Tags: vue3, nuxt

Hola el problema es que no puedo llamar imagenes con require porque me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
[worker] require is not defined
```

El codigo para llamar la imagen que estoy utilizando es este:

```
<img :src="require(image)" />
```

Estoy usando Nuxt 3 y tengo activo el SSR.
Llamar imagenes con import funciona pero esto no sirve en mi caso ya que necesito traer la imagen desde un objeto que contiene la ruta relativa.

No se exactamente que esta pasando y como puedo solucionarlo. Agradezco su apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno logre solucionar este problema agregando mis imagenes en la carpeta public
de esta forma puedo referenciar a ellas solo colocando:

```
   <img src="./public/products/3.jpg" />
```